# REST/Services: Only able to retrieve index. Everything else result in http error 500

Tags: services, 8

I am pretty new to Drupal, and I'm trying to get a webservice running on my Drupal 7 site.

For testing purposes, I made a Rest-service, with NO authentication, and all resource's added to it. I called this "test", with endpoint "test".

When accessing http://mysite.net/test/node I do get a nice list of all my nodes.
When accessing http://mysite.net/test/node/68 (or anything other than the index) I get a time-out, with http error 500 Internal server error in the headers. 
I have been googling the entire day, and come up with absolutely nothing.